# Присвоить input name такой же как у div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!

Помогите в решении вопроса.

У меня есть блоки с `input type="radio"`

Структура следующая

```
<div class="wrapper_all_radio0">
<input type="radio" id="radio01" name="radio" />
<input type="radio" id="radio02" name="radio" />
<input type="radio" id="radio03" name="radio" />
</div>
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы name изменялся на имя класса div , т.е. `name="wrapper_all_radio0"`  для всех инпутов внутри данного дива

И еще, каждый новый блок с классом `wrapper_all_radio0` изменяется javascript, т.е.  у первого блока класс  `wrapper_all_radio0`, у второго блока класс  `wrapper_all_radio1` и т.д.

Таким образом надо сравнить имя дива и присвоить соответсвующий name всем инпутам внутри каждого дива

Изменение класса дива выполняет следующий код

```
$(function(){
            $('.wrapper_all_radio').each(function(i){
                var $tc = $(this).attr('class')
                $(this).attr('class', $tc+i)
            })

        })
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете найти элементы внутри `div`’а с помощью метода `.find()`. Он принимает селектор, поэтому, чтобы найти переключатели, можно ему передать селектор `'input[type="radio"]'`:

```
$(function(){
            $('.wrapper_all_radio').each(function(i){
                var $tc = $(this).attr('class')
                $(this).attr('class', $tc+i)
                $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').attr('name', $tc+i) 
            })
})
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!